# TypeError: data type not understood opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

thats my python3 opencv3 code i get this error when i run this code i did't finished it yet that's are the error can some one help ?

```
line 19, in <module>
matches = bf.match(np.array(kpTrain, desTrain))
TypeError: data type not understood
```

that's my code

```
import numpy as np
import cv2


camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
orb = cv2.ORB_create()

img = cv2.imread('/home/shar/home.jpg')
imggray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


kpTrain = orb.detect(imggray,None)
kpTrain, desTrain = orb.compute(imggray, kpTrain)

ret, imgCamColor = camera.read()

bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)

matches = bf.match(np.array(kpTrain, desTrain))
```

Comment: Try - `bf.match(kpTrain, desTrain)`

Comment: TypeError: queryDescriptors is not a numpy array, neither a scalar

Comment: Ok sorry , try - `bf.match(np.array(kpTrain),np.array(desTrain))`

Comment: don't be sorry i get a new erorr TypeError: queryDescriptors data type = 17 is not supported

Comment: it's a conceptual error: you have to match 2 descriptors from 2 images, not the keypoints and descriptors from 1 image

Comment: i only changed the photo and the error gone the problem is probably in the function of the numpy module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again here, as in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31739179/typeerror-argument-given-by-name-k-and-position-2/35212565#35212565) you are trying to to match keypoints and the descriptors from one image. The matching of descriptors is done with two images.
1. Find Keypoints in 2 images
2. Calculate descriptors for the two images
3. Perform the matching.

In your case it should be something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

orb = cv2.ORB_create()

img = cv2.imread('/home/shar/home.jpg')
imggray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# load second image in grayscale
imggray2=cv2.imread('/path/to/image.jpg',0)

#Detector and descriptors for 1st image
kpTrain = orb.detect(imggray,None)
kpTrain, desTrain = orb.compute(imggray, kpTrain)

#Detector and descriptors for 2nd image
kpTrain2 = orb.detect(imggray2,None)
kpTrain2, desTrain2 = orb.compute(imggray2, kpTrain2)

bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)

matches = bf.match(desTrain,desTrain2)
```