# TypeError: Argument given by name ('k') and position (2)

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

Find below my `opencv3` **Python3** code to match objects which raises the following error:

> TypeError: Argument given by name ('k') and position (2)

Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time
import distance
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
img = cv2.imread('/home/shar/bo.jpg')
imgTrainGray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
kpTrain = sift.detect(imgTrainGray,None)
kpTrain, desTrain = sift.compute(imgTrainGray, kpTrain)
FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 0
index_params = dict(algorithm = FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, trees = 5)
search_params = dict(checks=50)  
flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params,search_params)

matches = flann.knnMatch(kpTrain,desTrain,k=2)
```

Ideas on how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me

```
FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 0
index_params = dict(algorithm = FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, trees = 5)
search_params = dict(checks=50)

flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params,search_params)
matches = flann.knnMatch(np.asarray(des1,np.float32),np.asarray(des2,np.float32),k=2)
```

Comment: Can you give any deeper explanation for this error? What is causing it?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to match keypoints and the descriptors - which is wrong. You need two images, first you find the keypoints in both of the images (points of interest). Then for each point you calculate a descriptor (again in both images). Finally, you use the Flann to find matches between the two images. See the example [here](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_matcher/py_matcher.html).

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass `k` as positional argument:

```
matches = flann.knnMatch(kpTrain,desTrain,2)
```

Comment: TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

Comment: @shar What `kpTrain` and `desTrain` contains before function call?

Comment: @shar Try to use `matches = flann.knnMatch(np.asarray(kpTrain,np.float32),np.asarray(desTrain,np.float32),2)`

Comment: matches = flann.knnMatch(np.asarray(kpTrain,np.float32),np.asarray(desTrain,np.float32),2)‌​
                                                                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier

Comment: @shar Can you provide full error traceback in your question? I tried this code and did not get syntax errors

Comment: File "sk.py", line 16
    matches = flann.knnMatch(np.asarray(kpTrain,np.float32),np.asarray(desTrain,np.float32),2)‌​
                                                                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier

Comment: @shar Ok, lets try to do it in 3 lines: `des1 = np.asarray(kpTrain, np.float32)  
des2 = np.asarray(desTrain, np.float32)  
matches = flann.knnMatch(des1, des2, 2)‌​`

Comment: File "sk.py", line 18
    matches = flann.knnMatch(des1, des2, 2)‌
                                           ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier

Comment: @shar Can you share you file?

Comment: @shar I have not found in this file line `matches = flann.knnMatch(des1, des2, 2)‌`. Looks like it's another file

Comment: @shar Try just to retype this line `matches = flann.knnMatch(des1, des2, 2)‌`, without using copy/past

Comment: File "sk.py", line 16, in <module>
    des1 = np.asarray(kpTrain, np.float32)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 462, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'cv2.KeyPoint'